# Get the current date and time from Google NTP server

Tags: java, android

I want to get the current GMT Time from Google ntp server. How can I modify the code with AsyncTask? Does the NTP server give a null value?

I know there is some issue in the below code.

```
SntpClient client = new SntpClient();
if (client.requestTime("time.google.com")) {
    long now = client.getNtpTime() + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - 
    client.getNtpTimeReference();
    Date current = new Date(now);
    Log.i("NTP tag", current.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have the NTP Server [library](http://support.ntp.org/bin/view/Support/JavaSntpClient).And Put your code inside try method. Hope It will works . :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm getting the time from Google with this code, you should try it.

What my code does is, it go to the `google.com` page and retrieve the time, after that I get the time in `"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"` this format, and then I convert it into seconds to upload to my server.

You will need to declare your String dateStr `private String mDateStr;`.

```
  protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {



            try{
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet("https://google.com/"));
                StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
                if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
                    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z",Locale.ENGLISH);
                    mDateStr = response.getFirstHeader("Date").getValue();
                    Date startDate = df.parse(mDateStr);
                    mDateStr = String.valueOf(startDate.getTime()/1000);
                    //Here I do something with the Date String

                } else{
                    //Closes the connection.
                    response.getEntity().getContent().close();
                    throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Response", e.getMessage());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }



            return null;
        }
.... it continues, thsi is an asynctask
```

Comment: I don't want this method. i already did it. it gives null value .